# Appcelator Titanium : Calling a function of parentWindow from childWindow?

Tags: javascript, titanium

```
Win1.js    
var Appwin = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
    function checkPage() {

    }
    Appwin.open();

Win2.js
    var childWindow = Titanium.UI.currentWindow(); 

    From here how i can call checkPage function
    childWindow.open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it for your setup is to include it on both files.

```
Ti.include('functions_files.js');
```

The other way you could do it is to define both windows in one file with the function and have the windows set to a url.

```
App.js

var Appwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'path/to/Win1.js'
});
var childWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'path/to/Win2.js'
});
function checkPage() {

}
Appwin.open();
childWindow.addEventListener('open', function() {
    checkPage();
});
```

As requested:

Win1.js

```
var Appwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({

});

Ti.App.addEventListener('checkPage', function(e) {
    var tableView = e.tableView;
});

Appwin.open();
```

Win2.js

```
var childWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({

});

var tv = tableView;

childWindow.addEventListener('close', function() {
    Ti.App.fireEvent('checkPage', {
        tableView = tv
    });
});
```

Comment: i want to call the function on the close of the button

Comment: `Ti.include('functions_files.js');` is still your best bet. change the `'open'` to `'close'` and you're set.

Comment: Nope. Put your function in a file say `functions.js` and then `Ti.include('functions.js');` in each of your files that need access to the function.

Comment: that function has a lot of properties which are dependent to that class like tableView etc

Comment: In that case you may want to look more into `eventFiring` so you can pass properties and methods if needed. https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.fireEvent-method.html and an example in the KS. https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/custom_events.js#L32

Comment: can u post a example with two files where i am accessing win1.js method is called during the close of win2.js... it would help me a lot

Comment: Can that function Win1.js be a normal function or should it be like Ti.APP

Comment: `Ti.App Event Listeners` are available globally so it needs to be as shown above.

Comment: Can you help me out in these two questions too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723534/ti-app-addeventlistener-behaving-strangely

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723557/setting-the-childwindow-focus-over-the-mainwindow